# Cannot Display Web Application in iframe On Chrome or Edge

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, windows-server

I am working on adding a very old web application to a site. We have to display the web application in an iframe on the site. When using Internet Explorer 11, the web application will display in the iframe without an issue. It should be noted that this is an old web app

Chrome and Edge on the other hand will display an error in the developer console: **Refused to display '{APPLICATION_URL}' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors {SERVER_NAME}".**

One thing to note is that **this will not always happen** in Chrome and Edge. I'd say about 80% of the time I will receive the error, but 20% of the time the application will load fine in the iframe and have no issues. This makes me think that maybe the issue is specific to a group of servers on our farm, but am unable to prove that.

I have very limited visibility over our servers here, but I can get someone else get me more information if that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. One thing to note: **Internet Explorer does NOT support the Content-Security-Policy header**. That is why this worked in IE 100% of the time. IE was unable to do anything with that header, so it just loaded the app like it thought it was supposed to.

I was able to work with some people who have access to the servers that the web application is hosted on. I found the problem was caused by an IIS setting for the default site that the applications on this one server belong to.

There are two servers that host the application, and a load balancer will direct you to a server depending on traffic. **One** of the servers added an HTTP header for the content security policy to all outbound traffic for the applications on the server. This explained why sometimes the app would load fine, and other times it would fail.